# How to convert a dictionary to an in-memory table in DolphinDB?

Tags: dictionary, datatable, dolphindb

For example, how to convert the dict `a = {"col1": 3, "col2":4}` to the following table?

```
col1    col2
3       4
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the dict are array(s), you can use the `transpose` function to convert the dict to a table as follows:

```
z=dict(`id`val,[`a`b`c,1 2 3]);
transpose(z);
```

In other cases, convert the values of the dict to array(s) and then use the `transpose` function, as shown in the following example:

```
a = {"col1": 3, "col2":4}
enlist:E(a).transpose()
```